# Trapezoidal shadow in xml for android

Tags: xml, android-layout, kotlin

I want to create a box of shadow for `<RelativeLayout>` for android as you can see from the image below:

[image]

The shadow-box drawable would be created with `<gradient>` inside of it as shown below:

[image]

I'm struggling because I'm trying to do it with a trapezoidal shape for the `<RelativeLayout>` to be seen as it stands up from the screen.

---

> **Here is my code:**

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#fff"
   tools:context=".LoginActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
       android:layout_width="354dp"
       android:layout_height="239dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="30.5dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="30.5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="84dp"       
       android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"    
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="48dp"
           android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"           
           android:contentDescription="avatar"
           app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

   </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### my_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <!-- image shadow below can be use just fine-->
   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/image_shadow">
   </item>

   <!-- drawn shadow below is what I want it to be trapezoidal shape -->
   <!-- right now it's a triangle, and I unsuccessfully tried to overlap it so it'd become trapezoid -->
   <item
       android:drawable="@drawable/drawn_shadow">
   </item>

   <item
       android:top="0dp"
       android:bottom="0dp">
       <shape
           android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid
               android:color="#d1d1d1"/>
           <stroke
               android:width="0.01dp"
               android:color="#9c9c9c"/>
           <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
               android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item
       android:top="0dp"
       android:bottom="2dp">
       <shape
           android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid
               android:color="#d1d1d1"/>
           <stroke
               android:width="0.01dp"
               android:color="#9c9c9c"/>
           <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
               android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item
       android:top="0dp"
       android:bottom="4dp">
       <shape
           android:shape="rectangle">
           <gradient
               android:angle="90"
               android:endColor="#564DA1"
               android:centerColor="#463894"
               android:startColor="#2D216F"
               android:centerY="0.75"
               android:type="linear" />
           <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
               android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item
       android:top="0dp"
       android:bottom="157.5dp">
       <shape>
           <gradient
               android:startColor="#564DA1"
               android:centerColor="#e8e8e8"
               android:endColor="#564DA1"
               android:type="linear"
               android:centerY="0.75"
               android:angle="90"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item
       android:top="125dp"
       android:bottom="4dp">
       <shape>
           <gradient
               android:startColor="#574EA4"
               android:centerColor="#574EA4"
               android:endColor="#574EA4"
               android:type="linear"
               android:centerY="0.75"
               android:angle="90"/>
           <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
               android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

### image_shadow.9.png

[image]

### drawn_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item >
       <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="45"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:pivotX="15%"
           android:pivotY="-36%" >
           <shape
               android:shape="rectangle"  >
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="50dp"
                       android:left="0dp"
                       android:right="0dp"
                       android:top="0dp" />
               <gradient
                   android:angle="225"
                   android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                   android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                   android:startColor="#999999"
                   android:centerY="0.1"
                   android:type="linear" />
           </shape>
       </rotate>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You can try by giving elevation to your relative layout.
i.e android:elevation="4dp"

Comment: @Maitri Ty for your advice. Adding `android:elevation` only expands the shadow downward, it doesn't make the shadow trapezoidal which is what I try to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#23FFC1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/box"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/shadow"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

box.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#422570"
        android:centerColor="#7E4DF0"
        android:endColor="#4D2779" />
</shape>
```

shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:viewportHeight="30"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <path
        android:pathData="M 5,0 L 95,0 100,30 0,30 5,0 z" >
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:endX="50"
            android:endY="99"
            android:startColor="#C47C7C7C"
            android:startX="50"
            android:startY="1"
            android:type="linear" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

Change the colour or size as required I simply used LinearLayout you can use Relative if you want.

Add this in your gradle.build even if you use androidx

```
defaultConfig {

    //...

    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

My Output
[image: Final Output with shadow]

Comment: Your drawable seems to be a perfect trapezoid. I really appreciate your time, but I really can't find a way to use `<vector>` as a shadow.

Comment: Oh, I see! You use `AppCompatImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

Put your layout in card view

If you want more shadow then increase the value of ' card_view:cardElevation="30dp" '

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardElevation="30dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#000"><!--
card elevation value 30dp and black background
-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="AbhiAndroid"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I did a research and found the shadow generated from CardView isn't trapezoidal.

Answer (score 0):

I can't manage to create a trapezoidal shape drawable file so far, but I successfully create a 9-Patch file for it.

First, I generate a 9-Patch file from https://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/, then I edit it with Adobe Photoshop by replacing the original shadow with the trapezoidal shadow, which I also used Adobe Photoshop to draw it, and save it back to the same file (image_shadow.9.png)

**image_shadow.9.png**

[image]